# Firebase FIRVerifyAssertionRequest causing uncaught exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-crash-reporting

I've setup crash reporting on my app via the Firebase Crash tool. I'm trying to tackle as many crashes as I can but there is one in particular that I am struggling with.

An uncaught exception is occurring when `-[FIRVerifyAssertionRequest unencodedHTTPRequestBodyWithError:] + 1128144` is called.

I have attached the full crash report as an image (the blur just covers my app name) and it would be great if someone could point me in the right direction so that I can fix this crash.

[image: Crash report]

**Update with code:**

I'm not totally sure what code is causing the crash but from the report I'm assuming it's being caused when my app receives a successful Facebook login notification as that is the only part of my code that uses `signInWithCredential`.

The code is as follows (obtained from the Firebase docs):

```
- (void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)fbLoginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error == nil) {

        FIRAuthCredential *credential = [FIRFacebookAuthProvider credentialWithAccessToken:[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString];
        [[FIRAuth auth] signInWithCredential:credential completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                //Process successful sign in, e.g. show home and hide login views.
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: It'll probably be easier to help if you show the minimal code that triggers the problem. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm not completely sure what code is causing the issues but I have added a snippet of code which is the only part of my code that uses `signInWithCredential `.

Comment: Any update on this bug? I'm running into it as well.